# api to create a new page on confluence

Tags: curl, confluence, jira-rest-api, confluence-rest-api

I am a member of a confluence group which I open from browser from the following URL

```
https://kensci.atlassian.net/wiki/collector/pages.action?key=MyKyey
```

Hitting this page gives me the login page, where I enter my credentials and go about creating a new page etc.

I would like to do this from an API. I have read several posts on the internet and feel that this below curl command should work.

```
curl -v -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","title":"new page","space":{"key":"ATTACH"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}' "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/?os_authType=basic"
```

However, what do I replace the URL http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/?os_authType=basic with? Do I replace it with the URL I open from my browser which is https://kensci.atlassian.net/wiki/collector/pages.action?key=MyKey/?os_authType=basic

I have tried this, so finally string looks as follows

```
curl -v -u myusername:mypassword -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","title":"new page","space":{"key":"ATTACH"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}' "https://kensci.atlassian.net/wiki/collector/pages.action?key=MyKey/?os_authType=basic"
```

But it does not create a page, and just spits out a huge amount of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your curl looks fine except from the url.

EDIT:
Please try replacing "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/?os_authType=basic" with the following: "https://kensci.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/?os_authType=basic". You might need to add "/collector" after "/wiki".

If that doesn't work please post the output you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following curl command. I tried that, and it works fine with my wiki url.

```
curl -v -S -u username:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'{"type":"page","title":"new page","space":{"key":"ATTACH"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new testpage</p>","representation":"storage"}}}' https://kensci.atlassian.net/rest/api/content
```